# Revision history shows links where it shouldn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, markdown-rendering

I just removed a link from what I think was a spam post.

In the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5685129/revisions), the second revision erroneously links a number of paragraphs as a result.

Comment: ...also true for strikeout and a lot of other formatting. I've always figured it might not be easily done 100.00% right.

Comment: @Arjan yeah, it is possible this is simply impossible.

Comment: I originally thought that its because you [forgot to remove](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44927b77-52e2-49db-a7b6-46d33ddbbf8c/view-source) `[1]:web_site_url` on bottom but still there is issue. so it might be a bug in diff engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have improved the revision diff algorithm.

We're currently testing it here on Meta; once we're certain there are no problems, it will go out to the other sites as well. Your example was one of those I tested, and it is handled correctly by the new version.

Comment: Cool. ----------