# Possible bug in previous versions' user interface

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, diff

I edited a question, and when I went to the versions page, I found this (possible) bug.

***The original answer***
[image]

---

***While in the previous versions page***
[image]

Notice the last line that starts with "in linux" is considered part of the code (have a gray shading) while in the question page it is not, and it shouldn't have that shading.

You can see the question answer mentioned in *[How do you install an APK file in the Android simulator?, Jorgesys's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-simulator/3480235#3480235)*.

Comment: by "previous versions page" you mean preview?

Comment: This has been getting reported a lot recently, in various incarnations: [Revision history shows links where it shouldn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87610/revision-history-shows-links-where-it-shouldnt), [What's going on here?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54262/whats-going-on-here), [Really weird (bad, confusing) version diff.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38031/really-weird-bad-confusing-version-diff), [Revision bug, bad formating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46334), [Wrong formatting after edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71809).

Comment: i mean revisions , that has urls that look like that http://stackoverflow.com/posts/xxxxx/revisions

Comment: @Loic: No, he means the edit or [revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/92039/revisions).

Answer (score 2):

We have improved the revision diff algorithm.

We're currently testing it here on Meta; once we're certain there are no problems, it will go out to the other sites as well. Your example was one of those I tested, and it is handled correctly by the new version.

Comment: great , glad that my example helped