# Misplaced code tag in edit revision differences

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, revisions-list, diff

The differences shown for revision 2 of [this edit revision summary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/97685/revisions) have a misplaced `</code>` tag, possibly related to the replacement of a code span adjacent to another code span.

As a result, most of the body of the text with differences is formatted as code (tested on Chrome 12.0.742.112):

[image: Misplaced Code Tag]

According to the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fposts%2F97685%2Frevisions&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), the page contains these errors:

> Line 144, Column 757: end tag for "CODE" omitted, but its declaration does not permit this
>
> Line 148, Column 131: end tag for element "CODE" which is not open

Comment: Wow, that's pretty weird.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in the [great diff engine refactoring of 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105387/115866). Before that, the diff engine only had a very limited understanding of HTML (it wasn't a lot more than a normal plain text diff on the HTML source). This caused some very unhealthy output in some cases, like the one you found. The new (well, not so new anymore, since I'm posting this in 2013) diff engine is a lot smarter than that, as you can see.